# I need help makeing a light flash while a stepper is constantly moving

Tags: arduino-uno, led, stepper, loop

The starter code.

```
#include <Stepper.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 120;  // change this to fit the number
// for your motor of steps per revolution

// initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 8, 9, 10, 11);

int stepCount = 0;         // number of steps the motor has taken
int LEDPin = 13;
void setup() {
  // initialize the serial port:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LEDPin,OUTPUT);
}


void loop() {
  // step one step:
  myStepper.step(1);
  Serial.print("steps:");
  Serial.println(stepCount=456);
  stepCount++;
  delay(35);
}
```

I want a light to flash in 15 sec increments while my stepper keeps moving. I basically want to combine that code with this one:

```
int LEDPin = 13;
void setup()
  pinMode(LEDPin,OUTPUT);
void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(LEDPin,HIGH);
  delay(6000);
  digitalWrite(LEDPin,LOW);
  delay(6000);
}
```

Comment: do you have a question? ............ note: `delay(6000);` causes the arduino to stop for 6 seconds ..... examine the code of the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example sketch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop() function, call two new functions. Let's call those maybeStep() and maybeBlink(). Each one of those reads the time, millis(), and subtracts the saved time when it last performed its action (stepping or toggling the LED). If that difference is >= the interval for that action, do the action and update the saved time to the current time.

Remember to make the saved times 'static' (or global) so they won't get over-written when these function return.

The BlinkWithoutDelay example program gives the general idea of how to read the clock instead of calling delay(), to decide when to perform each action.

Update:

> new at Arduino and don't quite know what you mean?

Your loop function would something like this:

```
void loop(){
   maybeStep();
   maybeBlink();
}
```

Notice that loop now does nothing but call your action functions. Here's an outline of one of the action functions:

```
void maybeStep(){
   if the time_now > than the time_we_last_stepped by 35 millisec, then
      step again and store the new time_we_last_stepped;

   return;
}
```

Notice that this function may or may not take a step! It decides whether to step by reading the time and comparing it to the time of the previous step. But either way - step, or no step - it returns quickly. The maybeBlink() function will work exactly the same way: compare the time it last toggled the LED on or off to the amount of time it should wait between toggles. Then either toggle it (and save the time and on/off state) or not, and in any case, return to the loop.

Done this way, your loop() function will call those action function very frequently - way more often than the actions need to take place. Most of those times, nothing will happen. But every once in a while (a "tiny while" in human terms), one of those functions will take a step or switch the LED. If you write your code this way, loop() could call dozens or hundreds of such functions and all of those actions could still take place on time.

The key to this programming technique - called non-blocking programming - is that the action functions be *very brief* . They must decide quickly whether something needs to be done, and either do it or not, then return immediately.

Comment: thank you, but I am new at Arduino and don't quite know what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The `delay()` function causes the Arduino program to stop in it's tracks and "count to 100". While it's doing that, it's not doing **anything else**.

Therefore delay is not an option when you're trying to do more than one thing at a time.

you need to rewrite your code to use the `millis()` function to tell if your desired amount of time has passed. something like this:

```
unsigned long nextLEDTime = 0;
bool ledState = false;
#define delay 6000

int LEDPin = 13;
void setup()
  pinMode(LEDPin,OUTPUT);
void loop()
{ 
  if (millis() >= nextLEDTime) //if it's time to toggle the LED
   {
     ledState = ! ledState;  //Invert the LED state
     digitalWrite(LEDPin, ledState);
     nextLEDTime = millis() + delay;  //Set nextLEDTime to the next time we need to do something
   }
}
```

Then you need to do the same thing with your stepper motor code, creating a separate variable to track the next time you want to do something with the stepper motor.

Put all your code in a single loop function that checks bot the nextLEDTime and the nextStepperMotorTime and takes appropriate action at the correct time for each thing you want to handle.